# What is the difference between popular and hot?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, hot-questions, popularity

With the new UI for the front page there is a popular questions tab and under that there is a hot questions sort:

[image: Screenshot, with "Popular" and "sort"]

What's the difference between a question being popular and a question being hot?

<sub>*Or to put it another way, is it hot or not?*</sub>

Comment: Actual number of views and/or activity probably, not sure.

Comment: I think "hot" just means how active they are over the past few days, but popular means either a lot of votes or a lot of links to the post. (This is just a guess, of course.) I'm taking the meaning of "hot" from the tooltip for the hot tab on the page I get when clicking the logo (I don't have the new navigation) and assuming it's the same meaning.

Comment: I have read that the difference becomes more pronounced after one leaves high school.

Comment: @MarkAmery You mean after graduation?

Comment: Hotness brings popularity, but popularity doesn't bring hotness. Someone  can be popular for many reasons, but there is only one reason why one is hot.

Comment: @MarkAmery You made my day.

Comment: Ask Kim Kardashian.

Comment: Amy Schumer is popular, but she's not hot.

Answer (score 47):

Popular questions have had high activity over time.  Hot questions have more recent activity.  So hot and popular means lots of historic activity and recent activity.  Popular but not hot denotes a "classic" question that has had activity for a longer period of time.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected) for reference

Comment: Can you provided any references for that? It seems like everyone has their own opinion on it.

Comment: @David Grinberg
I found: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question

^ For what makes a popular question.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected

^ For what determines a hot question.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Your (edited) second link is broken. Please correct it.

Comment: @Firelord fixed, but you really could have done that yourself.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I don't have sufficient reputation to make edits on Meta here (you do realize it has different rules for editing, don't you), otherwise I would've done that already.

Comment: @Firelord: Hmm, what are the different rules for editing?

Comment: @Firelord I didnt realize there were different rules. I thought anyone could suggest an edit?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg There are no suggested edits on Meta. (I don't think this applies to tag wiki edits, I think those can still be suggested.) Therefore, to edit on Meta, one must have 2k rep. Or, of course, be the owner of the post. (This also does not apply to Meta Stack Exchange, just the per-site metas.)